# select2 jQuery plugin: how do I get a reference of the list of <option> tag replacements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

with the following code

```
$('select.my-select').select2().on('select2:opening', function (event) {
  console.log(event, this);
});
```

the logged `this` is the 'original' `<select>` DOM element. But how do I get its `replacement`/`representation`? I'm talking about the `<ul>` with class `select2-results__options`.

I'm using the latest select2 beta version (currently 4.0.0 Beta 3).
thanks

Comment: Do you have more than one select2 on that page?

Comment: @Fenistil not simultaneously. why? I can't just select that class because what I need to do is to apply a css change on each  `<li class="select2-results__option">` based on the value of its corresponding `<option value="valueIneedToUse">` tag. So I need somehow to get a reference of both at the same time.

Comment: Ok, but you have written that you want to select the `<ul>` tag, not the `<li>s`. So would you like to pair every `<li>` to the original `<option>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

If I was right, the `<li>s` in the `<ul>` are in the same order as the `<option>s` in the original `<select>`.

So you can select the `<ul>` then go through its childs and get the corresponding `'.

Try this one:

```
$('select.my-select').select2().on('select2:opening', function (event) {
    var $select = $(this);
    $('.select2-results__options > li').each(function(i) {
        var option = $('option:nth-child('+i+')',$select);
        console.log($(option).val());
    });
});
```

Ps.: I can't test it now, but if you provide a Fiddle, it can be tested.

Or if you want to style the results, try this one (this code is for select2 3.5.1, but I think it should work with 4.0 too):

```
$('#myselect').select2({
    data: categories,
    allowClear: true,
    formatResultCssClass: function(obj) {
        if (obj.disabled) { return 'select2-item-cat-parent'; }
        else { return 'select2-item-cat'; }
    }
});
```

Comment: this might even work but it's super hacky, thanks anyway for trying to help. I thought there was a clean way to do this through the select2 API, but maybe there isn't. I'll submit a pull request probably.

Comment: @kuus I don't think it's a hacky way.. Think about it, if this function is included in the API of select2, then it's not a hack, otherwise it is? I understand what you say, but I don't think that everything should included in the API, if it can be achieved with a few lines of code. Maybe the inner API would be better in performance and provide cleaner code, but in my opinion it's not a thing where performance is really important.

Comment: sorry I didn't explained myself very clearly. I wouldn't put this function in the API, but this (see [commit](https://github.com/kuus/select2/commit/7d239229135d9f25b8758d33f7746f5e8f8e560f)). I want to achieve this: set style attributes on the `<li>`s based on the `<option>` value. I can use the `opening` event to loop through all options and set my desired style attribute on the option tag (then the `<select>` DOM reference in the function above would be enough. In the action of creating the `<li>`s then select2 would copy over the `option.style.cssText` if any.

Comment: @kuus: Have you ever tried to look at `select2 formatResultCssClass` function? I have updated my answer including this function, try it.

Comment: that function doesn't seem to be in 4.0

Comment: @kuus Try to find information about `templateResult`, you can read about it here: http://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html  But the documentation for that is missing yet, maybe you can try to find out how to use it from the select2 source itself.

Comment: Yes I managed to use `templateResult`, but still would be nice to be able to act on the `<li>` itself through the API I think. If you're a mantainer of select2 you could maybe consider it, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the maintainer, I'm just a user :)